# HTTP routes aren't getting called with SocketIO being initialised

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So i was trying to build an app which uses socket.io for messaging and express routes to deal with regular http requests . The issue is that http calls to those routes don't happen and i get a socket.io error as shown below

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Transport unknown"
}
```

the way i have implemented the express server and socket.io is

```
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: FRONTEND_CORS,
    })
  );

  // setting up socket io
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    path: "/",
    cors: {
      origin: FRONTEND_CORS,
      methods: ["GET", "POST,"],
      credentials: false,
    },
  });
  io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
  });
  
    httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });

  app.use(voucherRoutes);
```

here `voucherRoutes` represent the http routes that i tried accessing

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/fetchVouchers", FetchAllVouchers);
router.post("/api/addVoucher", CreateVoucher);
router.get("/api/getCurrentId", FetchCurrentId);

export default router;
```

I am happy to provide any more details required and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading and re-reading the docs i figured out how to do it
so you just set the path of the socket to listen to a specified path like say
/chat

```
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    path: "/chat",
    cors: {
      origin: FRONTEND_CORS,
      methods: ["GET", "POST,"],
      credentials: false,
    },
  });
```

following this set your io object with app.set

```
  app.set("socketio", io);
```

set up a route called /chat (since i set the socket to listen on /chat)

```
router.get("/chat", function () {
}
export default router;
```

and that should prevent socket from listening on other routes thus letting you make http requests on other routes.